# HP Application SysInfoEx - Pop Up On Start

Tags: windows-10

This always pops up on start, but it's hard to ascertain whether this is a legitimate application.  I've disabled it from starting in Task Manager (in Task Manager, it's called HpseuHostLauncher, but when it pops up, it's called SysInfoEx).

How can this be permanently disabled, or is this an infection?

Comment: It could be the HP Shortcut key manager.  Try disabling that function.  There is a possible solution in this HP support article.   https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Disable-Shortcut-Hotkeys/td-p/5577368

Comment: Thanks - that led me to the culprit (it's a bit different). In the start menu, it's called `HP System Event Utility` and uninstalling it makes it go away.

Comment: Does my post help you? I could post the answer if so

Comment: @John - yes, I checked it as the answer. For the solution, you can just add for people to uninstall the `HP System Event Utility`. That worked. It was your answer that helped me find it. Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the HP Shortcut key manager or another HP utility. It is more likely this than malware or a virus.

Try disabling that function. There is a possible solution in this HP support article.

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Disable-Shortcut-Hotkeys/td-p/5577368